# module not found when using include in django

Tags: python, django, include-path

I'm trying to use include in my app following the tutorial here - https://www.w3schools.com/django/django_views.php

it seems that when I run the server using this configuration-

`urlpatterns = [path('members/', include('mimi.urls')), path('admin/', admin.site.urls),]`

**I get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mimi'.**

I've attached a screenshot of my Pycharm project folder as it is now.
[image]

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. It seems to fail to recognize anything outside the web_questions folder, but I can't find a way to give it the absolute path.
I'm running the server using this command line -

```
py web_questions/manage.py runserver
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So like people have said here before ,the app directory should be under the project directory!
The way to do it easily, and without transferring manually the folders, is to run this line of code-

```
django-admin startproject <project_name>
cd .\<project_name>
python .\manage.py startapp <app_name>
```

**The second line is what made all the difference for me**, and I didn't see it in the tutorial.
This way everything is created in the correct hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

That web_questions folder content should be in the same directory as mimi.

[image: Example.]

Comment: I've tried moving the web questions folder to the mimi folder, but it still doesn't work. and It's kinda weird that by following the tutorial the two folders are created seperately

Comment: No. Package is represented as folder with that dark dot inside. Your web_questions package should be on the same level/indent as mimi package.

Answer (score 0):

please check wheather your module "mimi" is present in the INSTALLED_APPS List in the settings.py file. If not u can add it in INSTALLED_APPS List.

Comment: man... I've already tried doing this :(